# Adding Icon on a button on NetBeans

Tags: user-interface, button, netbeans, icons

I have a problem whereby I can seem to be unable to see my icon image on the button on NetBeans. It works very well on Eclipse by showing button text with the icon, but when I move the code to NB it does not display the icon just the text. Could someone help me with this problem.

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class MyFrame  extends JFrame implements ActionListener{ //implements allows the button to perform action
 JButton button = new JButton(); //making a button global. Declare outside the contructor
    
    MyFrame(){
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("icon.png");//adding an Icon
        
        
        button = new JButton();
        button.setBounds(200, 100, 200, 100);//poistion and size
        button.addActionListener(this); //To make the button work, so it display what you need to display
        button.setText("CLICK ME"); //Set text to the button
        button.setFocusable(false); //Removes the border aroound the button text
        button.setIcon(icon); //Adding icon to a button 
        button.setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER); // setting alignment for the button
        button.setVerticalTextPosition(JButton.BOTTOM);
        button.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans", Font.BOLD,25)); //setting font for the button
        
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setSize(500,500);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.add(button);
    }
    //METHOD FOR ACTION LISTENER
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource()==button){ //to check event occours with our button
            System.out.println("YESSIR"); //displaying what I want when I click the button
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The icon file cannot be found. Assuming your image is stored under src/main/resources/icons/icon.png you would load it with:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/icon.png");
```